# How to decrypt data received from kinesis in AWS lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have configured my lambda to get triggered from AWS kinesis.

The handler receives the event and i get the log in cloudwatch as below :

```
{'Records': [{'kinesis': {'kinesisSchemaVersion': '1.0', 'partitionKey': 'MSFT', 'sequenceNumber': '49626331424383135829970932456737647485340372651235868706', 
'data': 'eyJwcmljZV90aW1lc3RhbXAiOiAiMjAyMS0wMi0wMSAwOTozMDowMC0wNTowMCIsICJzdG9ja2lkIjogIk1TRlQiLCAicHJpY2UiOiAyMzUuMCwgIndlZWs1Mm1heCI6IDM0OS42NzAwMTM0Mjc3MzQ0LCAid2VlazUybWluIjogMjI3LjE3OTk5MjY3NTc4MTI1fQ==', 'approximateArrivalTimestamp': 1643650596.425}, 'eventSource': 'aws:kinesis', 'eventVersion': '1.0', 'eventID': 'shardId-000000000002:49626331424383135829970932456737647485340372651235868706', 'eventName': 'aws:kinesis:record', 'invokeIdentityArn': 'arn:aws:iam::799034532258:role/kinesis_sns_dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:799034532258:stream/stock_streams'}, {'kinesis': {'kinesisSchemaVersion': '1.0', 'partitionKey': 'MSFT', 'sequenceNumber': '49626331424383135829970932456972179094345617239479156770', 'data': 'eyJwcmljZV90aW1lc3RhbXAiOiAiMjAyMS0wMi0wMSAxMDozMDowMC0wNTowMCIsICJzdG9ja2lkIjogIk1TRlQiLCAicHJpY2UiOiAyMzcuOTc5OTk1NzI3NTM5MDYsICJ3ZWVrNTJtYXgiOiAzNDkuNjcwMDEzNDI3NzM0NCwgIndlZWs1Mm1pbiI6IDIyNy4xNzk5OTI2NzU3ODEyNX0=', 'approximateArrivalTimestamp': 1643650691.538}, 'eventSource': 'aws:kinesis', 'eventVersion': '1.0', 'eventID': 'shardId-000000000002:49626331424383135829970932456972179094345617239479156770', 'eventName': 'aws:kinesis:record', 'invokeIdentityArn': 'arn:aws:iam::799034532258:role/kinesis_sns_dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:799034532258:stream/stock_streams'}, {'kinesis': {'kinesisSchemaVersion': '1.0', 'partitionKey': 'MSFT', 'sequenceNumber': '49626331424383135829970932456979432649263312367511404578', 'data': 'eyJwcmljZV90aW1lc3RhbXAiOiAiMjAyMS0wMi0wMSAwOTozMDowMC0wNTowMCIsICJzdG9ja2lkIjogIk1TRlQiLCAicHJpY2UiOiAyMzUuMCwgIndlZWs1Mm1heCI6IDM0OS42NzAwMTM0Mjc3MzQ0LCAid2VlazUybWluIjogMjI3LjE3OTk5MjY3NTc4MTI1fQ==', 'approximateArrivalTimestamp': 1643650799.27}, 'eventSource': 'aws:kinesis', 'eventVersion': '1.0', 'eventID': 'shardId-000000000002:49626331424383135829970932456979432649263312367511404578', 'eventName': 'aws:kinesis:record', 'invokeIdentityArn': 'arn:aws:iam::799034532258:role/kinesis_sns_dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:799034532258:stream/stock_streams'}]}
```

Not sure, how to retrive back my data. I am sure, its encrypyted in "data" attribute in the above received json.

I am woking in python. Any idea how to decrypt my data in lambda_handler?

Thanks,
Nilotpal

Answer (score 3):

That's not encrypted, it's Base64 encoded. [The official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis-create-package.html#with-kinesis-example-deployment-pkg-python) includes example Python code to decode the data payload.